# How to SSR a react app and serve using Actix web(Rust web framework)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, vite, actix-web

I wrote a website with react,typescript, tailwindcss, vite, package-manager as yarn. For SOE reason I need to do SSR using any lib like express, next. I am going to write my web server and backend in rust so I need a compiled version of my whole react project into a single HTML files so that SOE also can parse the html doc and single files serving will be better. Don't be harsh on me I am new to web development.... Help me with this and also suggest me some best practise to follow in web development, It could be handy...

I wrote a web server to serve the html, css, javascript that vite build generate but web content are in javascript so SOE cannot understand that..

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use the [ssr-rs crate from crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/ssr_rs).

The maintainer has a project called [reactix](https://github.com/Valerioageno/reactix) that does what you're asking about.

To be clear, I have not gotten his projects to ssr react, but he has at least 2 years ago.

This is an Issue I am currently working on myself and I have found the only way is to use the [deno_core](https://crates.io/crates/deno_core) crate or the [V8](https://crates.io/crates/v8) crate itself.

However be aware that module imports do no work as expected so it is best to have all you JS on one file.

Comment: I also have a repository that shows my current attempts to get this to work.

https://github.com/RileySeaburg/rust-react-ssr